# Is there a command-line command to cycle through gnome-shell 3.34 workspaces?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, 19.10, multi-touch, gestures

The context here is that I'm using [cunidev/gestures](https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures) to set up mac-like three-finger gestures for my laptop, for window switching. What I have right now is:

- a three-finger upwards swipe triggers `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.show();'`
- a three-finger downwards swipe triggers `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.hide();'`

I'd like to have three-finger leftwards and rightwards swipes to cycle through the workspaces in gnome-shell. I know it's possible to use `xdotool` to trigger keypresses that can call the shortcuts set up in Settings > Devices > Keyboard Shortcuts, but I'd rather use a gesture to tell gnome-shell directly what to do, rather than having to use a gesture to trip a keyboard shortcut that tells gnome-shell what to do.

I've checked a few places, but Google and [the gnome-shell docs](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en) don't have it, and the [gnome-shell wiki's list of gestures](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/Gestures) seems to be a goal rather than a description of the software as it exists.

I'm running gnome-shell 3.34 on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Three-finger swipes work correctly for me. I'm trying to find the necessary command-line invocation to get gnome-shell to switch to an adjacent workspace.

Comment: Oh right, sorry.